# Sharepoint 2013 Forms Based Authentication Application Forbidden error 403

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, forms-authentication

I am developing a Provider-hosted application for SharePoint 2013.

I debug this application on a Development Collection with both Windows Authentication and FBA (Form Based Authentication) activated. I can successfully access to this collection with my Windows account or a user stored in SQL Server. Both accounts are administrators of the collection with full control on it.

When I run the application, I get the usual window asking for the authentication mode I want. After being successfully connected with a user (both are working), I get : "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" on clientContext.ExecuteQuery().

```
var contextToken = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);
var hostWeb = Page.Request["SPHostUrl"];

using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(hostWeb))
{
   clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   Response.Write(clientContext.Web.Title);
}
```

I should precise that, if I disable the FBA on the collection and only let the Windows authentication, it works like a charm.

What am I doing wrong ? Any idea ?

thanks for helping

Comment: Did you figure out a solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void Whatevermethod()
    {

        using (SP.ClientContext clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://server/collection"))
        {
            //Configure the handler to set FBA mode
            clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<SP.WebRequestEventArgs>(ctx_MixedAuthRequest);

            //Use the default mode to execute under the credentials of this process
            clientContext.AuthenticationMode = SP.ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;


            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }

    private void ctx_MixedAuthRequest(object sender, SP.WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Add the header that tells SharePoint to use FBA
            e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var hostWeb = Page.Request["SPHostUrl"];

using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(hostWeb))
{
    clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest);
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Response.Write(clientContext.Web.Title);
}


static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.